# Two virtual hosts in one config file

Tags: apache-virtualhost

Is it possible for me to have two virtual hosts (ports: 80 & 443) in one config file? i.e.

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.test.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.test/public
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.test.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.test.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.test
    ServerName example.test
    ServerAlias www.example.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.test/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I ran `sudo a2ensite example.test.conf` and restarted Apache.

Upon trying the above (`https://example.test`) setup, I receive:

[image]

In the browser. So, not the actual site contents? It's fine when served over `http`

Comment: Have you enabled the sites? At the moment they're in `/sites-available/` and there's no indication you've used `a2ensite` to enable them

Comment: Yes, I ran `sudo a2ensite example.test.conf`

Comment: And restarted Apache?

Comment: yes, I restarted Apache

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for me to have two virtual hosts (ports: 80 & 443) in one config file?

Yes.

However, with regard to your testing, there isn't an https://example.text virtual host defined in the configuration you've shown us. What you do have is:

- https://miperformance
- http://example.test

Comment: Yes, that was a copy/paste mistake, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. See: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-20-04 for a full tutorial.